# std::bad_cast exception thrown by dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, c++03

in the code below, I get a `std::bad_cast` exception thrown when casting `derived.properties_` from `BaseProperties` to `DerivedProperties`. Looking at the code, it seems to me like something is going wrong when intialising the `BaseProperties` with a reference to the `DerivedProperties` in the `Base` class constructor.

What I am trying to achieve is a simple UI where `Base` is essentially my Component interface and `Derived` is anything that is considered a Component. It seems like a fair assumption that Components may have different properties but have some similar ones, such as size and position.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how best to achieve my aim?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Properties for all objects of Base type
class BaseProperties {
public:
  BaseProperties( std::string baseProperty ):
    baseProperty_( baseProperty ) { }

  virtual ~BaseProperties(  ) {  }
  std::string getBaseProperty(  ) { return baseProperty_; }

protected:
  std::string baseProperty_;
};

// Properties specific to objects of Derived type
class DerivedProperties: public BaseProperties {
public:
  DerivedProperties( std::string baseProperty, std::string derivedProperty ):
    BaseProperties( baseProperty ),
    derivedProperty_( derivedProperty ) {  }

  std::string getDerivedProperty(  ) { return derivedProperty_; }

private:
  std::string derivedProperty_;
};

class Base {
public:
  Base( BaseProperties& properties ):
    properties_( properties ) {  }

  virtual ~Base(  ) {  }

protected:
  BaseProperties& properties_;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived( DerivedProperties properties ):
    Base( properties ) {  }

  friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream& out, const Derived& derived );
};

std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream& out, const Derived& derived ) {  
  return out << derived.properties_.getBaseProperty(  ) << ", "
             << dynamic_cast< DerivedProperties& >( derived.properties_ ).getDerivedProperty(  );
}

int main(  ) {
  Derived derived( DerivedProperties( "BaseProperty", "DerivedProperty" ) );

  std::cout << derived << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are storing a reference to a temporary.  At some point one of your classes needs to take ownership of the `DerivedProperties` you are passing in.

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but maybe it's still helpful: Note that the need to do a `dynamic_cast` here seems suspicious. You should not require a derived property in a context where you only have access to a base property. Either provide a virtual interface that will allow you to solve the task with just using the base property, or make the derived property directly available in the context where it's needed. Resorting to `dynamic_cast` is almost always a worse option.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: At some point I'd still have to use `dynamic_cast` to make the derived property available. I have a function that returns the property via a `dynamic_cast` however I ommitted it here to try and keep the code shorter, unless there is another way to do so..

Comment: @ctor _At some point I'd still have to use dynamic_cast to make the derived property available_ - Why do you say that? In a proper design, you should almost never have to do a `dynamic_cast`, even if it's hidden inside some nice getter function. See if you can think about a way that you can avoid the need for the cast in your current program altogether. If you have a hard time figuring it out, consider paying the fellows at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) a visit, they are usually great at helping out with problems like this.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: The only potential way around a `dynamic_cast` I can see, is by using a `static_cast`, since I know the type is what I expect it to be.

Comment: @ctor You're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. The base type should already provide all the functionality you need, so there should be no need to cast. What good is an abstraction if you anyway have to break it open by casting to the concrete types all the time? Design your types in a way that abstractions are powerful enough to serve your needs. If this is not possible for your design, consider throwing out the abstraction. Virtual inheritance does have significant runtime costs, so if it cannot make your life easier for a specific problem, don't use it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derived class should take a `DerivedProperty&` as parameter, similar to how your Base class does it:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived( DerivedProperties& properties ):
    Base( properties ) {  }

  friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream& out, const Derived& derived );
};
```

Since you're not taking a reference as constructor parameter but an actual object, you're actually storing a reference to a temporary object, that does not exist anymore once the constructor has exited.

Comment: My hope for passing it as an object was to eliminate the need for `const DerivedProperties&` which meant I couldn't create `Derived` with `Derived d( DerivedProperties( "PropertyOne", "PropertyTwo" ) )`.  However it seems that this is the only way to do it without completely redesigning it.

Comment: Actually, if you change the type to `const BaseProperties&` in both constructors and in the declaration of `properties_ `, creating a `Derived` instance with: `Derived d( DerivedProperties( "PropertyOne", "PropertyTwo" ) )` should work. Of course, it depends if const properties are acceptable in your case.

Comment: Should have said, const properties aren't acceptable as I override any attempt to create a property with 0 height or width, although if I allowed them I could probably get away with const properties so long as I didn't need to ever change them.

Comment: Ok. Btw, if you did create a property-containing object that way, you would still have an invalid property reference problem when the `BaseProperties` instance you pass to the constructor goes out of scope...

Answer (score 1):

When the `Derived` constructor ends, the `properties` argument will be destroyed. However, you've stored a reference to that object, so that reference is now left dangling. Instead, you should make the `properties_` member not a reference.